# Random numbers for Rabin-Miller primality tests

Tags: prime-numbers, pseudo-random-generator

I've implemented a Rabin-Miller primality test fuction following Wikipedia and the book Applied Cryptography. Now I'm using it for generating primes with a string seed. The book suggests the following for this:

1. Generate a random 'n'-bit number
2. Set the high- and low-order bits to 1.
3. Make sure it is not divisible by small primes $p\in[2,2000]$.
4. Perform a Rabin-Miller Test for some random $a$. Choose a small value of $a$ to make it go quicker. Do five tests (I'm doing 40 as a post suggested here, and instead of generating a random number, I increment by one and test again.

So, first I used a random generator with uniform distribution to generate $a$, but after reading this, I changed it to the standard C++ `rand()` with `srand(time(0))` seed. It is faster, but I'm not sure if it is the best way. Using boost's Twister was slower, but gave a wider range of $a$. I have searched (maybe not with right keywords) but **how does choice of $a$ influence the test?**

Is it good if the range is pretty small compared to the size of the number I test (saying $a$ is 32 bits, and the number is 512 bits)? Will it increase the odds of a false positive (pseudo prime)?

Comment: Note for step 3. Make the product of the small primes and store it as constant in the library. Later when step 3 is required calculate `GCD(n, productOfSmallPrimes)`, If one then it is not divisible any of the small primes, otherwise return step 1. This is much faster then dividing the list of small primes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental property of the Rabin-Miller primality test is that, if the value $N$ being tested is composite, then it will return "composite" at least 75% of the time.  That is, if we define the function $RabinMiller( N, A )$ that runs the Rabin-Miller test against the number $N$, using $A$ as a witness, then for any composite $N$, $RabinMiller( N, A )$ will evaluate as "Composite" for more than 75% of the values of $A$ in the range $[2, N-1]$.

So, you question is "what happens if we don't chose $A$ uniformly from the range $[2, N-1]$; what happens if we chose $A$ from a much smaller range?

The answer to that is that nobody really knows; we know that at least 75% of the numbers in $[2, N-1]$ will reveal $N$ to be composite, however there are no proven results how they might be distributed (there is a proof if we assume an unproven conjecture within number theory, but until we get a proof of that conjecture, it doesn't count).  It would appear to be reasonable to conjecture that they are, in fact, reasonably well distributed, however we don't know that.

Hence, if you select your value $A$ from a smaller range, then while you probably have a good test, you have just voided the probabilistic provability that Rabin-Miller gives you.

In addition, there is also this fact that works in your favor; the Rabin-Miller proof states that, for any fixed composite $N$, that at least 75% of the values $A$ will return "composite", however for a random composite $N$, then $A$ will return "composite" almost all the time.  While there are certain composite $N$ where a random $A$ will have a $\approx 25$% chance of returning "probably prime", however those $N$ values are rather rare (significantly rarer than primes).  What this means is that, in practice, Rabin-Miller works significantly better than the proof would suggest.

So, that's the bottom line?  Well, if you're interested in retaining the provability aspect of Rabin-Miller, you rather have to select values from the full range (and it's not all that expensive when compared to running the Rabin-Miller test).  On the other hand, if you just want something that is likely to work, selecting from a smaller range is, as far as we know, reasonable.

Comment: Thanks! I knew the "probable prime" false positives occur more often than you say, but it's good to know that they don't. I've decided to use the range [2, N-1]. +1

Comment: @PnD/@poncho: It is worse than "just voided the probabilistic provability" if small easy to guess value are used in M-R test, in fact this behavior can be seen as opening a hole. Because rand()+srand(time(0)) is deterministic construct, it is possible that attacker might create pseudo-prime which has been carefully chosen that it will pass all R-M tests for those specific tests (at specific point in time). For small number of tests (like 5) it is possible. However, for large number of tests (like 40) it will be very hard to abuse this.

Comment: That's true, I know I should avoid this kind of rng (with e.g time as seed). Now I'm using the twister, which is said to be pretty good. Also, could somebody give a link/tell sg about the unproven conjecture(mentioned in the 3. paragraph.)?

Comment: You can restrict the range to $\:$[2,N-1)$\:$. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @PnD You should use a well seeded CSPRNG, not a mersenne twiser. The seeding part is essential, `/dev/urandom` is the minimum quality you should accept as seed.

Comment: @CodesInChaos/@Ricky Thanks for the advice, I will change them.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a test using an integer from a restricted range, if that's faster (Speed is the only reason you're considering a restricted range, right?), as an efficient way to weed out most composites, and if that succeeds perform the 40 tests using the full range.